# How to settle crying toddler after nap

Tags: toddler, tantrums

Our son cries up when his mom is not next to him and it will go on for hours and I eventually loose my temper but It is not his fault not mine fault, he sleeps next to his mother since he was born but I really want to find out how to make him stop crying when his mom isn't at home and he wakes up to find she is gone somewhere for work.

Any tips on how to stop crying toddler after nap would be really helpful

Comment: Your son must learn to sleep independently or you need to start cosleeping with him, too. Precious Little Sleep is a good book/online resource. Good luck.

Comment: Please tell us how old your son is. Also, have you ever heard of sleep training? What does your wife think of all of this?

Comment: @anongoodnurse he is 3 years old. Well initially like every mother she wants her baby to be next to her but now he slips into his side of bed, during which the bed is tight and sometimes he get scolded by his mom to go back to his bed. I don't blame him coz he is used to sleeping next to her and still figuring out that baby and parents bed are different. He is very quick at picking things so he has reduced it a lot but as he is growing up the crying after nap is getting more.

Comment: Can you please edit this info into your question?

Answer (score 3):

My son is also a 'grumpy napper' and wakes up from nap very unhappy.  For him, the key points are to go to him as fast as possible when he wakes up, and respond in a happy, cheerful way even if he's starting to tantrum, and then as soon as possible engage him back into the day.  This usually means afternoon snack or going outside to play, but any favorite activity may work.

Once he enters the post-nap grouchy mood, no amount of comforting him seems to help, and he will just cry and cry and escalate into a tantrum, but pushing through and getting on it with it in a reassuring and cheerful way helps him return to a better mood.

An alternate thing to try is to time his naps so that he's awake when his mom leaves.  Some kid are confused, disoriented and distressed when a parent 'just disappears' while they sleep, and can rationalize and cope with the separation more if they have a chance to hear mom or dad say goodbye and remind them of the time they will be back (it helps to use routine-centric language like "I'll be back after lunchtime" or "I'll be back before you take your bath"-- anything that they understand to happen on a predictable cadence).